# Will the [Value] field in customized object be parsed to boolean strongly while indexing?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I am encountering a problem while I indexing some data into ElasticSearch

Here is the context.
I want to index below content into elastic search as below, and in which has a [value] named field:

```
// source#invokingMethods
{
            "appName": "mytest1",
            "businessInfo": "pay",
            "className": "com.mytest.biz.pay.SinglePayProcessor",
            "id": "mytest1516625397380",
            "methodName": "validatePayRequest",
            "properties": {},
            "version": "17855",
            "desc": true,
            "key": 17855,
            "value": "11-aa"
 }
```

When I indexing, I got an exception from ES server:
"type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse [invokingMethods.value]",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Failed to parse value [11-aa] as only [true] or [false] are allowed."
        }

Is the [value] field a preserved field in ES, and it could not be parsed in boolean type?

Any feedback will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the mapping of the index?

Comment: Thanks Sammy. I just checked mapping of the index, the field of [value] is: ,
                                    "value": {
                                        "type": "boolean"
                                    },
But I have no idea when or how I specifically set it into boolean type.
Is this the reason the [value] field only support boolean value while indexing?

Comment: I would think so. Try deleting the index and re-creating the index with new mapping.

Comment: I tried and succeed! The mapping of this field is changed to text, so it's able to handle almost all kinds of types. :) Thanks Sammy.

Comment: You might not have specifically set it to boolean but Elasticsearch implicitly figures out a mapping type when you first put a document. I am guessing the value for "value" for the first document you put could have led ES to interpret it as a boolean type.

Comment: I posted my comments as an answer so you can accept it,

Comment: No value filed is not preserved in elasticsearch

Comment: @prasadkp, why do you think so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not have specifically set it to boolean but Elasticsearch implicitly figures out a mapping type when you first put a document. I am guessing the value for "value" for the first document you put could have led ES to interpret it as a boolean type.

Try deleting the index and re-creating the index with new mapping.